# TypeError: _react2.default.PropTypes is undefined (I am already using PropTypes from package)

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I upgraded my react app to v.16+, so I know that I need to use PropTypes from package instead of React, but I just can't figure out what's wrong in my code. I am already using PropTypes from package and the webpack bundle my app without errors, but on the console in the browser I see: "**TypeError: _react2.default.PropTypes is undefined**".

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connectRange } from 'react-instantsearch/connectors';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';
import numeral from 'numeral';


class Range extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentValues: { min: this.props.min, max: this.props.max },
    };
    this.onValuesUpdated = this.onValuesUpdated.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(sliderState) {
    this.setState({
      currentValues: {
        min: sliderState.currentRefinement.min,
        max: sliderState.currentRefinement.max,
      },
    });
  }

  onValuesUpdated(values) {
    this.setState({ currentValues: { min: values[0], max: values[1] } });
  }

  onChange(values) {
    if (
      this.props.currentRefinement.min !== values[0] ||
      this.props.currentRefinement.max !== values[1]
    ) {
      this.props.refine({ min: values[0], max: values[1] });
    }
  }



render() {
    const { min = 0, max = 0 } = this.props;
    const { currentValues } = this.state;

return (
  <div className="ais-Slider__root">
    {currentValues.min === undefined && currentValues.max === undefined
      ? null
      : <Slider
          max={Math.trunc(max)}
          min={Math.trunc(min)}
          onAfterChange={this.onChange}
          onChange={this.onValuesUpdated}
          range
          value={[currentValues.min, currentValues.max]}
        />}
    <div className="ais-Slider__values">
      <div>
        {numeral(this.state.currentValues.min).format('0,0')}
      </div>
      <div>
        {numeral(this.state.currentValues.max).format('0,0')}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);


 }
}

Range.propTypes = {
  currentRefinement: PropTypes.object,
  max: PropTypes.number,
  min: PropTypes.number,
  refine: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Thanks anybody for the time and advice.

Comment: Check your various dependencies do not implicitly peer-depend on older versions of React *or* prop-types. Might be easiest to `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` and watch the output for peer dependency errors/warnings.

Comment: Do a full project search for `React.PropTypes` and see if anything is still trying to use it.

Comment: Chase DeAnda, this is the only file where I use PropTypes. When I am not importing this file into parent Component, there's no error. 

user268396, okay, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Okay, I removed some packages and changed the version, then run npm install and it seems like the console throws no errors for now. So thank you user258396 for your advice.